# ConcurrentModificationException when invoking putAll

Tags: java, hashmap, guava, concurrentmodification

I have difficulties in understanding the following error.

Suppose you have a class A in which I implement the following method:

```
Map<Double,Integer> get_friends(double user){

Map<Double,Integer> friends = user_to_user.row(user);
//friends.putAll(user_to_user.column(user));

return friends;}
```

Then in the main I do the following:

```
A obj = new A();
Map<Double,Integer> temp = obj.get_friends(6);
```

Well this works fine. However when I uncomment the follwing line in class A:

```
friends.putAll(user_to_user.column(user));
```

and I run again the program, it crashes and throws me the concurrentModificationException.
It is to be noted, that I am creating the Table user_to_user as follows:

```
private HashBasedTable<Double,Double,Integer> user_to_user;//
user_to_user = HashBasedTable.create();
```

What is further surprising is that when I interchange the way I am filling friends, I mean in that way:

```
Map<Double,Integer> friends = user_to_user.column(user);
friends.putAll(user_to_user.row(user));
```

Then everyting will work fine.
Any idea ?

Comment: Please follow java naming convention..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `HashBasedTable` is internally implemented as a `Map<Double, Map<Double, Integer>>`, and that the implementation of `user_to_user.column(user)` is iterating over the rows at the same time you're modifying the row associated with `user`.

One workable alternative would be to copy `user_to_user.column(user)` into a separate `Map` before putting it into the row.